# Stop Java returning error on upload

Tags: java, flash, mime-types

I've got a problem where I'm trying to add the ability to upload an MP4 to an existing Java app that previously handled FLVs.

The Flash is stopping the process, because it receives this helpful error:

```
{
    "error": 0,
    "message": null,
    "payload": null
}
```

And the Java shows this error:

```
 > 110677 [qtp868385821-30] WARN org.jets3t.service.utils.Mimetypes -
 > Unable to find 'mime.types' file in classpath
```

However, the upload continues and works fine.

Ive tried adding the mime.types file to the classpath, and it doesn't seem to make any difference. I've added the `mp4`file type to `mime`.types

```
 video/x-mp4            mp4
```

Any idea how I get the server to either accept mp4s, or stop sending the error so the rest of the application can do its thing?

Comment: you say `However, the upload continues and works fine.` - so is it working or not?

Comment: Yeah the upload works, it's success just doesn't get reported to Flash because of this error I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JetS3t` includes a mime.types file in the classpath root. 
This is the file Synchronize expects to find in the classpath, 
is this file present in your configs directory? If not, you may need to replace it.

If you don't wish to use the mime.types file to guess the mimetype of your files, 
you can get rid of the warning message by changing the following line in

```
log4j.properties:

log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.utils.Mimetypes=INFO
```

to read:

```
log4j.logger.org.jets3t.service.utils.Mimetypes=ERROR
```

Comment: We're using TomCat6, Java6 and Primefaces. I'm not sure if we're using JetS3t? Forgive my ignorance.. I'm new to this game! I can't find the configs directory atm

Comment: see your question `WARN org.jets3t.service.utils.Mimetypes`

Comment: ha! Oh yes. Thanks. Would the configs directory be called something else. I can find the JetS3t jar, I can't find the configs for it

Comment: So do I need to create a configs directory under the main root folder and add the mime.types file there? I'll try that

Comment: from the javadocs `... loads mime types from the file mime.types if this file is available at the root of the classpath.`

Comment: Hmm OK thanks. It was at the root of the classpath. Will try finding other places it might be looking for it

Answer (score 1):

Try including the `mime.type` in `src/main/resources` if you're using Gradle. An [example mime.type](https://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/src/bbf2a7b4807539007df309341e2aed0d40f5db01/configs/mime.types?at=default) file is found in the [project source code](https://bitbucket.org/jmurty/jets3t/wiki/Home).